# WSO2 EMM: Error when installing App from store

Tags: java, wso2-iot

I've been installing WSO2 EMM 2.0.0 and i've been stuck at this problem for a while now:
When i try to install an app from EMM's App Store (when i click on the 'install' button), nothing happens on the webpage (no error message) and nothing happens on the device. Looking at the logs, i can see there's a java Error. Here's that error from the logs:

> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-02-23 15:54:19,490] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -  org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "id" from null (/scripts/registry/artifacts.js#31)
>   org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "id" from null (/scripts/registry/artifacts.js#31)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
>           at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.authenticator.framework.WebappAuthenticationValve.invoke(WebappAuthenticationValve.java:43)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> ...And then some.

the root of the problem is this :

> TypeError: Cannot read property "id" from null (/scripts/registry/artifacts.js#31)

But i have no idea what this "id" (or artifact.id, as it seems to be in the artifacts.js file) fails to fetch.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this the released version witch can be downloaded on the WSO2 web site ? Or did you use build it from the source ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a configuration issue. Please go through the documentation and follow it step by step. What is the type of the application? Is it an Android one?

Comment: I've followed the documentation (several times), the result is the same. Yes, it is an Android app.